# Classifiers that support weighting of the instances

Tags: r, boosting, weighted-sampling

I'm thinking of implementing my own boosting algorithm, so I'm looking for any multiclass classfication algorithms that would support weighting of the examples, i.e. you could specify what examples are more important to affect algorithm optimisation.

Of course I know about decision trees, but I'm looking for something else, maybe some other rule learning techniques.

I want to do this in R, so it would be good if algorithms would be implemented there.

Comment: Maybe this question would be more appropriate on Stackoverflow? Since it asks about exact implementations of the algorithms that supports instance weighting.